How is a Sturm sequence applied to the eigenvalue problem of a matrix.
As an exercise I am trying to implement a simple Lanczos eigenvalue solver for a large sparse symmetric matrix of size $n$ (A is $n$ x $n$).  I am able to find arbitrary eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  The next step is to ensure that I find all eigenvalues between $a$ and $b$.
I've read that a Sturm sequence can be used to count the roots between $a$ and $b$.  When I looked up Sturm on wikipedia I can see how it applies to polynomials.  When I attempted to apply this to the eigenvalue problem I ended up with a very large equation:
$Av=\lambda v$
$det(A - \lambda I) = 0$
The degree of this polynomial gets large quickly and seems like a bad approach.  I believe I am going down the wrong path because by forming and taking $n$ derivatives and divisions seems very costly while the point of Lanczos is to simplify the problem.  I never got off the paper stage to try writing the computer algorithm.
What is the proper way to apply the Sturm sequence to the eigenvalue problem?  Or is this even a good approach?

Applying the Sturm sequence to this eigenvalue problem may be accomplished by using the generalized form, $A\nu = B\nu\lambda$.  This can be rearranged as $[A-\lambda B]\nu = 0$.  We can now look at the bracketed term as a shift.  If we assume a value for $\lambda$ and then preform an LDL* decomposition, the number of negative terms in $D$ is the number of roots below $\lambda$.
So for the number of terms between $a$ and $b$ we do $D_1 = LDL(A-aB)$, $D_2 = LDL(A-bB)$ then $n_1 = (D_1 < 0)$, $n_2 = (D_2 < 0)$ and the final count is $n_2 - n_1$.
Note that if $a$ or $b$ is exactly an eigenvalue, the shift term is singular.
